# xmlrpc() error: (-1001) unable to parse URL during Drush command

Tags: drush, updating

I have an odd error coming from Drush when I perform module updates and other commands (it's most consistently comes from module updates). Near the end of the command execution this message pops up:

> xmlrpc() error: (-1001) unable to parse URL

Some cursory Googling produces that its likely an error popping up in [drupal_http_request](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7). I'm not sure where however since I'm not too familiar with the Drush code base.

I ran drush with the `--debug` switch for more information but that didn't tell me much other than this message typically pops up after the `drush_cache_command_clear()` being executed.

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the issue was the [APC](https://www.drupal.org/project/apc) module. After some testing I was able to isolate the issue during cache clear.

```
[shawnconn@host www]$ drush cc all
'all' cache was cleared.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 [success]
xmlrpc() error: (-1001) unable to parse URL                                                                                                                                                                                                              [error]
[shawnconn@host www]$ drush dis apc
The following extensions will be disabled: apc
Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
apc was disabled successfully.                                                                                                                                                                                                                           [ok]
You need to enable the APC module for remote cache clearing to work. Run drush pm-enable apc.                                                                                                                                                            [error]
[shawnconn@host www]$ drush cc all
'all' cache was cleared.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 [success]
[shawnconn@host www]$
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems likely that you have not correctly specified the URI for your site.  You can do this in one of several ways:

1. `--uri=http://example.com` on the commandline.
2. `'uri' => 'http://example.com'` in a site alias.
3. `$options['uri'] = 'http://example.com'` in a drushrc.php file.

For the purpose of most Drush commands, it is sufficient to use the name of the folder that contains the settings.php file as your uri -- or you do not need to specify the uri at all if the sites folder is 'default'.  However, some modules will need the full URI, including the http:// protocol, or you will experience problems similar to what you describe above.

Comment: Thanks for reply Greg (and all for all the awesome work with Drush!). I tried all those options and I still wasn't able to get rid of the problem. Turns out the cause was the APC module.